# Is there an easier way to call these functions using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Instead of using

```
<input value="" type=text id="DPRnumber" onkeydown="javascript:backspacerDOWN(this,event);" onkeyup="javascript:backspacerUP(this,event);">
```

Is there an easier way to call these functions using jQuery? Something like:

```
$('#DPRnumber').on('onkeydown', 'input', function(e) { ... I don't know ...
```

Comment: "I don't know" --- have you made any research?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. Use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with multiple events.

Try this:

```
$('#DPRnumber').on({
  keydown: function(event) {
    backspacerDOWN(this, event);
  },
  keyup: function(event) {
    backspacerDOWN(this, event);
  }
});
```

**Edit**:

Although we do not know what exactly your `backspacerDOWN()` function is doing, if you do not want to use `this`, then just replace all occurrences of `this` with `document.getElementById('DPRnumber')` like this:

```
$('#DPRnumber').on({
  keydown: function(event) {
    backspacerDOWN(document.getElementById('DPRnumber'), event);
  },
  keyup: function(event) {
    backspacerDOWN(document.getElementById('DPRnumber'), event);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why "This" event? Isn't "This" another word for id="#DPRnumber". I'm still learning. :)

Comment: [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a special keyword in Javascript (and programming) giving a reference to the current DOM object in this case. Where `this` is being called in my answer is equivalent to `document.getElementById('DPRnumber')`.

Comment: @user1022466 Just watch out.  jQuery can change `this` on you, and you may not expect it.

Comment: Thanks :) Is there another way to write this without "this"? What is the long way? Trying to understand ... :) Thanks.

Comment: @user1022466 - I have removed this from my answer. See my edit.